# Adding an EJB to a web application in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I was following a tutorial on how to create a web application in netbeans using Java EE 6. The tutor added a new bean by just right clicking on the project name->new->session bean. When I tried to follow the same instruction, I didn't find the session bean when I went to new. I am using netbeans 6.9.1. Is there a way to add it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add, the session beans, by using project pane on the left side. (If this is not showing, Press `Ctrl + 1` or go to windows -> select `Projects`)

Then to add the session beans

- Right your project
- Go to New
- Find Session Beans, If not go to others
- There find a category called "Enterprise JavaBeans"
- Select `Session Bean`
- Continue and complete the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

(Just guessing, because I use netbeans 7)
Project name->new->other
In categories, select Enterprise JavaBeans, and in file types, select Session Bean :)